# Join (Include) Between Model and AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Several time, i need to get the name of user in AplicationUsers (aspnetusers). Like in Chamado model (table) i have a column Id_Agente (user). With a simple List, i will get something like:

"3q0aju9-9ijuso-9sodkci..."

```
public class Chamado
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Abertura { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Id_Agente { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public String NomeAgente { get; set; }    
}
```

To work around, I created a NotMapped field and filled it with a foreach:

```
using (IdentityContext id2 = new IdentityContext())
{
    foreach (var item in historicos)
    {
        item.NomeAgente = id2.Users
        .Where(u => u.Id == item.Id_Agente)
        .Select(u => u.Nome).FirstOrDefault();
     }
}
```

But now I need to group Chamados by Agente, and it's becoming more and more harder, to work around. I tried to make another notMapped on chamados model named Qtde, make a list and extract from that list but returned a error:

```
public List<PainelChamados> ListarOrdem()
                {
                    using (SistemaContext db = new SistemaContext())
                    {

                        var chamados = db.Chamado
                            .Where(c => c.Situacao != Chamado.Esituacao.Concluido)
                            .GroupBy(c => c.Id_Agente)
                            .Select(c => new Chamado { Id_Agente = c.Key, Qtde = c.Count() });

                        using (IdentityContext id2 = new IdentityContext())
                        {
                            foreach (var item in chamados)
                            {
                                item.NomeAgente = id2.Users
                                  .Where(u => u.Id == item.Id_Agente)
                                  .Select(u => u.Nome).FirstOrDefault();
                            }
                        }

                        var query = chamados
                            .Select(c => new PainelChamados
                            {
                                Agente = c.NomeAgente,
                                Qtde = c.Qtde

                            });             

                        return query.ToList();
                    }
                }
```

Last, but not least, how could I just Include aspnetusers table like another regular table:

```
var query = db.Suporte_Projeto
                    .Include(l => l.Licenciado)
                    .Include(c => c.Condominio)
                    .Include(pr => pr.ProjetoProduto)
                    .Include(p => p.ProjetoAcesso);
```

[Chart Data](http://prntscr.com/a1pavt)

[Error](http://prntscr.com/a1pc5e)

Answer (score 0):

I did another work around! It's seems to be a good option while i cant join aspnetusers to my models table:

```
public List<PainelChamados> ListarOrdem()
        {
            using (SistemaContext db = new SistemaContext())
            {      
                var query = db.Chamado
                    .Where(c => (c.Situacao != Chamado.Esituacao.Concluido && c.Id_Agente != null))
                    .GroupBy(e => new { e.Id_Agente})
                    .Select(lg => new PainelChamados
                    {
                        CodAgente = lg.Key.Id_Agente,
                        Qtde = lg.Count()
                    });

                UsuarioData ud = new UsuarioData();
                List<PainelChamados> Lista = new List<PainelChamados>();

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Lista.Add(new PainelChamados
                    {
                        CodAgente = item.CodAgente,
                        Agente = item.CodAgente == null ? string.Empty : ud.GetAgenteId(item.CodAgente),
                        Qtde = item.Qtde
                    });
                }
                return Lista;              
            }
        }
```

What do you think, is it the best way to work around? I could return the list i desired.

[Chart With Agente Names](http://prntscr.com/a1w0c0)